# Can I get the "interesting" feed on iOS?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

I'm intrigued that the "interesting" feed isn't an available sort option on the stack exchange iOS app.

Or have I just missed it?

If it's not there, why not?

Comment: Closely related on Meta.SE: [Add a front-page-like tab to the iOS app's main site view](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229706)